# How can I cache installing my dependencies in a Dockerfile, when downloading them with FetchContent_Declare?

Tags: c++, docker, cmake

I am writing a c++ project where I download and install all my dependencies using `FetchContent_Declare` with cmake. The project structure looks like:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── CMakePresets.json
├── Dockerfile
├── get_dependencies.cmake
├── get_grpc.cmake
├── run_unittests.sh
├── src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── GribManager
│   ├── RoutingLib
│   ├── RoutingLibTests
│   └── RoutingPython
```

Where there are two `.cmake` files for downloading the dependencies. These look like:

```
include(FetchContent)

message(STATUS "Getting iGraph")
FetchContent_Declare(
    igraph
    URL https://github.com/igraph/igraph/releases/download/0.10.4/igraph-0.10.4.tar.gz
    URL_HASH MD5=10a3f325425970c75a7ba8359376e208
    FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS NAMES igraph
    SYSTEM
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(igraph)
target_compile_options(igraph PRIVATE -O3)

message(STATUS "Getting GEOS")
FetchContent_Declare(
    GEOS
    URL https://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.11.1.tar.bz2
    URL_HASH MD5=5732ec96b391ecddc35bda9795b654ea
    FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS NAMES GEOS
    SYSTEM
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(GEOS)

etc...
```

Then in my top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file, I install them by just including the `.cmake` files:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_compile_options(-fPIC)

project(RoutingLib C CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_OLD "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3")
include(get_grpc.cmake)
include(get_dependencies.cmake)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_OLD})

add_subdirectory(src)
```

My docker file to build my project, run the unit tests, build the python bindings etc looks like:

```
FROM quay.io/pypa/manylinux2014_x86_64:latest

RUN export MY_INSTALL_DIR=$HOME/.local
RUN git clone --recurse-submodules --depth 1 --shallow-submodules https://github.com/grpc/grpc
WORKDIR /grpc
RUN mkdir -p cmake/build
# WORKDIR /grpc
RUN cmake -DgRPC_INSTALL=ON -DgRPC_BUILD_TESTS=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$MY_INSTALL_DIR && \
    make -j 4 && \
    make install

WORKDIR /

COPY run_unittests.sh run_unittests.sh
RUN chmod +x run_unittests.sh

COPY CMakePresets.json CMakePresets.json
COPY get_grpc.cmake get_grpc.cmake
COPY get_dependencies.cmake get_dependencies.cmake
COPY CMakeLists.txt CMakeLists.txt
COPY src src

RUN mkdir build
WORKDIR /build
ARG BUILD_VERSION="0.0.0"
ARG PYTHON_EXECUTABLE="/opt/python/cp310-cp310/bin/python"

# Run unit tests in debug
RUN cmake .. --preset debug_linux -DBUILD_VERSION=${BUILD_VERSION} -DPython_EXECUTABLE=${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}
WORKDIR /build/Debug
RUN cmake --build . --target routinglib_unittests

# Run code coverage
WORKDIR /
RUN ./run_unittests.sh

WORKDIR /build
# Build python package
RUN cmake .. --preset release_linux -DBUILD_VERSION=${BUILD_VERSION} -DPython_EXECUTABLE=${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}
WORKDIR /build/Release
RUN cmake --build . --target python_package
WORKDIR /build/Release/src/RoutingPython/dist
RUN auditwheel repair WeatherRouting-0.0.0-cp310-cp1310-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Because I need to run the configuration steps, I need my 'src' directory. Every time this changes, the configuration stage and building my dependencies are not cached.

I am not sure how I can modify this to both keep it easy to install, and be able to cache/download my dependencies in a separate step.

Comment: you should do all your `FetchContent_Declare`s before doing any of your `FetchContent_MakeAvailable`s. See [the docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html#command:fetchcontent_makeavailable) for why.

Comment: I don't know anything about docker, but you can control directories used by FetchContent. See [the directory options of `ExternalProject`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html#command:externalproject_add). Is your problem solvable by configuring the `FetchContent` directories of the things you fetch? If so, which directories do you need to control and where might you want to put them to solve your problem? (feel free to [ping me in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/11107541) if you want extended discussion)

Comment: @user I will give those options a go and let you know, thanks :)

Comment: Read the `Dockerfile` reference for the `--mount=type=cache` option of `RUN`. However, as for me, [Earthly](https://earthly.dev/) do this job better. I use it for quite enough time and am pretty happy.

Comment: Just checking: your problem is that the `cmake .. --preset debug_linux -DBUILD_VERSION=${BUILD_VERSION} -DPython_EXECUTABLE=${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}` (and later) commands are run when changes are made in the `src` directory. And, specifically, that the iGraph and GEOS dependencies are being re-installed?

Comment: @datawookie Yeah, cmake is redownloading the libraries when src changes and GRPC is a big library so takes a long time to download and install. I have previously just used vcpkg for external dependencies but It would be good to know how to solve this, with just using CMAKE. In this example, I installed GRPC separately but that could also be added with FetchContent_Declare

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It would be helpful (to me anyway!) to improve the focus of this question. Are the lines following `RUN cmake .. --preset debug_linux -DBUILD_VERSION=${BUILD_VERSION} -DPython_EXECUTABLE=${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}
WORKDIR /build/Debug` relevant to the question? At present, whenever you update a file on the host under the `src/` directory this invalidates all steps beyond `COPY src src`, which is what is causing the `cmake` command to be run again. I don't know an awful lot about CMake, so getting more clarity on this issue would help me solve your problem.

Comment: Can you add the contents of `src/CMakeLists.txt` to your question too please?